# How can I prevent an html form from redirecting when it's still incomplete?

Tags: html, css, forms, redirect, submit

So I'm coding exclusively in HTML and CSS for this project. I have certain parts of my form marked as required. At the bottom, the submit button looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="location.href='thankyou.html'">
```

When I click submit, even if the required spaces are blank, it still directs to that page which says it's been submitted succesfully. I want it to stay on that page and show that the form is incomplete and only successfully submit when the required spots are filled.

Comment: In HTML you could use the required attribute for every needed input. But I recommend, doing that also in JavaScript. However, are you aware of the content of onClick not being HTML, instead there is some JS... Why do you not use the form action for the upcoming page?

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, replace the `click` function and validate the required fields have data. If not call the `event` object method `preventDefault()` (or if you are using jQuery return false).

An example:

```
$('.form').unbind('click').click(function (e) {
    if (!check_form()) {
        e.preventDefault(); //This could also be return false as I'm using jQuery.
    }
}
```

The jQuery documentation is here: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/
And the MDN documentation for `preventDefault` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `onsubmit` handler of the `form` element for this. If you return `false` from the handler, the form won't submit, if you return `true`, it does:

```
<form action="some-action.html" method="post" onsubmit="return checkIfFieldsAreEmpty()">
  <input type="text" name="blah">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
  function checkIfFieldsAreEmpty(){ /* logic to check fields */ }
</script>
```

Important: the way you set up an `onclick` event handler on the submit button will actually prevent your form from submitting completely (it just loads a new page with the form never submitting; so remove that event handler.

I leave it as an exercise to you to implement the actual checking logic in the function as I don't have access to your HTML.